# How can i make a PDF file load fast into the PDFVIEW library and How do i set progressBar?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have an App in which i would like to display a progressBar while waiting for the PDF to load from my firebase. But I have tried putting the load function on the OnpostExecute then calling the execute on the Oncreate. ***The problem is that it takes too for the pdf to load from my firebase into my pdfViewer hence may cause a user to quit the App. How can I make it load quickly??
And the progressBar stops even before the file has loaded.*** Below, I have attached some of the code I used. And I have used the Android pdfViewer Library.

**In Summary, How can I make a PDF file load quicker into my pdfViewer and How can I make sure that the Progressbar only stops when the PDF has successfully shown??** Thanks in Advance.

Here is my`onCreate()` and I used an AsyncTask

```
public class Geo2009Paper1 extends Activity {
PDFView pdfView;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private ProgressDialog pd;
RetrievePDFStream task;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pdf_viewer);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.simpleProgressbar);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    pdfView.enableSwipe(true);
    showProgress();
}
protected class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStream> {
    ProgressBar bar;
    public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 10) {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return inputStream;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if (this.bar != null) {
            bar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
        else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo2009Paper1.this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("No Internet");
            builder.setMessage("Internet is required. Please Retry.");
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); // calling builder.create after adding buttons
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
  private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager)      getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
public void showProgress() {
    task = new RetrievePDFStream();
    task.execute("My PDF Url");
}
```